# Find $||L(f)||_{V'}$ for a normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V = C^1([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$, the set of continuously differentiable functions on $[-1,1]$. $V$ is equipped with the norm $||f||_1 = \sup_{x\in[-1,1]} |f(x)|$.

Define a linear continuous map $L:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $L(f) = \int_{-1}^{1} \sin(\pi t)f(t) dt$.

I am trying to find the value of the $||L||_{V'}$, the norm in the dual space.

I have found that $|L(f)| \leq 2 ||f||_1$for all $f\in V$. So I expect that $||L||_{V'} = 2$. However I have not been able to find a function that satisfies $$\sup_{||f||_1 = 1} |L(f)| = 2$$ which would give me the answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: $\lvert L(f)\rvert \leqslant \int_{-1}^1 \lvert \sin (\pi t)\rvert\cdot\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt$

Comment: That's how I showed that $||L||_{V'} \leq 2$, I'm not sure how to use this to show the equality.

Comment: Then be a little more conservative with your estimates. You can find a smaller bound. Note, however, that for all $f\neq 0$ we have $\lvert L(f)\rvert < \lVert L\rVert_{V'}\cdot \lVert f\rVert_1$, so you need to work with the supremum to show you can get arbitrarily close.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll give this a go now, thanks.

Comment: I haven't been able to get tighter estimates, all I can see is $$|L(f)| \leq \int_{-1}^{1} |\sin(\pi t)| |f(t)| dt \leq \int_{-1}^{1} |f(t)| dt \leq \sup|f(t)|\int_{-1}^{1} 1dt$$

Comment: $$\int_{-1}^1 \lvert \sin (\pi t)\rvert\cdot \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant \int_{-1}^1 \lvert \sin (\pi t)\rvert\cdot \lVert f\rVert_1\,dt = \lVert f\rVert_1\cdot \int_{-1}^1 \lvert \sin (\pi t)\rvert\,dt$$

Comment: @Dman: If you follow Daniel’s line of reasoning, then you will obtain $ \| L \|_{V'} \leq \dfrac{4}{\pi} $. It appears that one cannot exhibit a function $ f \in V $ with sup-norm $ 1 $ such that $ |L(f)| = \dfrac{4}{\pi} $. Such a function would have to be the restriction of the signum function to $ [-1,1] $, or the negative of the restriction, neither of which are continuous, let alone continuously differentiable.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore you are right. Could you suggest another approach?

Comment: Define a $ (0,1) $-indexed sequence $ (f_{\epsilon}: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R})_{\epsilon \in (0,1)} $ of continuous (but non-$ C^{1} $) functions with sup-norm $ 1 $ by
$$
\forall x \in [-1,1]: \qquad
{f_{\epsilon}}(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if $ x \in [-1,- \epsilon] $}; \\
\dfrac{x}{\epsilon} & \text{if $ x \in [- \epsilon,\epsilon] $}; \\
1 & \text{if $ x \in [\epsilon,1] $}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $ \displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} |L(f_{\epsilon})| = \frac{4}{\pi} $. You can now approximate (in the sup-norm) each $ f_{\epsilon} $ by a function in $ V $ with sup-norm $ 1 $.